# Swift: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when initializing UIlabel value

Tags: ios, swift, null

I'm pretty new to swift (I usually code in Java and C++), and I'm building my first ios app.
In this app, I'm trying to create a picker view, and the problem is when I'm trying to set the initial value of the label point to the first item in the picker view (array) it pops up the error

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value"

Here is my code I'm working

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate{


    @IBOutlet var usertypeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Picker: UIPickerView!
    var usertype_array = ["patient","nurse"]
    //var usertype: String!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        super.viewDidLoad()
        usertypeLabel.text = usertype_array[0] //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return usertype_array.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!{
        return usertype_array[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
        var rowselected = usertype_array[row]
        usertypeLabel.text = rowselected        
    }
}
```

Any idea why the error happens? Note that it stills runs if I delete that line of code. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the posted code. I think error is somewhere else. Even the line usertypeLabel.text = usertype_array[0]  should run fine.

Comment: I'd guess you didn't connect your `IBOutlet` with label in storyboard

Comment: Did you create a label in the story board and connected it to the IBOutlet?

Comment: I control drag the label in the storyboard to the code in the Viewcontroler.swift. Do I miss any step to connect it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `UIPickerViewDataSource` and add it here:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource
```

And in your `viewDidLoad` method add this:

```
Picker.dataSource = self
Picker.delegate = self
```

And here is your full working code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{


    @IBOutlet var usertypeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Picker: UIPickerView!
    var usertype_array = ["patient","nurse"]
    //var usertype: String!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Picker.dataSource = self
        Picker.delegate = self
        usertypeLabel.text = usertype_array[0] //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return usertype_array.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!{
        return usertype_array[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
        var rowselected = usertype_array[row]
        usertypeLabel.text = rowselected
    }
}
```

If your outlet is correct it will work fine.

Check [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=90583945161916531370) sample for more Info.

Comment: I tried your code and it got an error at  Picker.dataSource = self.
I'm not sure if I miss anything anywhere...

Comment: Thank you for your help Dharmesh. Sorry it may sound dumb but how can I check it?
I created the picker and label in the storyboard, for the picker, I went to the connection inspector and link the delegate and dataSource to the yellow button in the viewcontroller. Then I control drag those 2 to the Viewcontroller.swift
Is it the correct way and order to do it? Thanks

Comment: Here it is: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=50687844781234858340
Thank you so much for your help Dharmesh. Really appreciate it.
I'd love to know why I got that error if possible.